# ERC1410 Security Token

Tags: erc-20, erc-721, erc-223

I am searching for an ERC1410 security token contract source code (must be tested) to implement in another contract, there is a github repo available but it is written in the beginning that the code is not tested. Can anyone provide me a tested code ?

It will be appreciated

Comment: i don't think anybody have tried to implement it yet. So if you need to implement it you should read the document and implement your own

Comment: Yes. What is your budget?